# Autolayout reseting views after changing frame in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, autolayout, xcode6

I am trying to change some frames inside the code but I want autolayout to be respected.

I have this hierarchy

[image]

When I hit the search button on top right of navigation bar, I want the green view to go up 50px. It is working great but the tableView is not following the autolayout since its top is binded on the green view.

So when I hit the button I have a blank space between the navigation bar and the table view.

Any ideas how can I sort this out using autolayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using auto layout, frame is dynamic based on constraints. Each time the view layout, it will recalculate by constraints and update view's frame. So instead of changing the frame of green view, you should change corresponding constraints.

Make a constraint reference in code call `topSpace` which is the constraint between green view and top layout guide and set its constant to -50 when user tap the button.

Comment: But do you recommend creating all the constraints in code or just bind the top one to a variable and change it?

Comment: I did not recommend creating constraints in code.  You can link top constraint with IBLayout and modify it.

Comment: yeah, just created an IBOutlet and made the changes... never though of that. Thanks a lot.